# Error 4xx AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Severe integrity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Good afternoon people,

I created an environment in Elastic Beanstalk and uploaded a NODEjs application an api with express.

She's working fine, all right.

But the integrity of the environment is reported as serious, and this monitoring attempt appears in the logs.

[image: Severe]

```
----------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/access.log
----------------------------------------
172.31.46.198 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.1.181 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.30.127 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.46.198 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.1.181 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.30.127 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.46.198 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.30.127 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.1.181 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:43 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.30.127 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.1.181 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.46.198 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:14:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
172.31.30.127 - - [03/Nov/2021:19:15:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 139 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this, without turning off the monitoring?

Comment: please download and check the complete EB logs

Comment: Probably the health checker is directed to a route for which does not exist in the node application.

Answer (score 0):

Good night people,

I found the problem, I didn't have anything set in my API's root on "/", so EB tried to monitor the api state and took a 404.

I set up a HealthCheck on the root "/" and normalized the 404 errors and integrity issue in the environment.

[image: success]